# Change IP using Jest and Supertest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, nestjs, supertest

I'm following the documentation of [nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing) to create my e2e tests.

Now I'd like to create requests and change the IP, because I have an interceptor accepts requests only from a range of ip.

Now I try to create it in my e2e class

```
const req = require('express/lib/request');
const CLIENT_IP = '1.2.3.4';
beforeEach(() => {
  // Mock the `ip` property on the `req` object  
  let ip = jest.spyOn(req, 'ip', 'get').mockReturnValue(CLIENT_IP);  
});
```

but the ip remains the same (my error: 'Not a valid IP ::ffff:127.0.0.1').

I tried to change the ip in my init setup like:

```
app.set('Remote-Addr', '1.1.1.1')
```

but the error is the same (and I don't like this approach.

How can I decide a specific ip for each requests?
I'm using express

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why you need to mock the client ip address, you should be sending it as a http header e.g. `x-client-id` or `x-forwarded-for`.

Which means that if you are writing a NestJS e2e test using supertest, you should be able to manually set the ip-address in the header e.g.

```js
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from 'http';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';

it('Create a new user -> (201) success', async () => {
  const requestHeaders: IncomingHttpHeaders = {
    'x-client-id': '1.1.1.1',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  }

  const requestBody: User = {
    name: 'joe blogs',
    age: '65'
  }

  const { statusCode, body } = await app.inject({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/v1/users',
    headers: requestHeaders,
    payload: requestBody,
  });

  expect(statusCode).toEqual(HttpStatus.CREATED);
  exoect(body).toBeDefined();
 });
```

Comment: I've just tried this out, but this doesn't work. People may want to mock the client IP for things like rate limiting.